# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '(inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<_>, inout Int) throws -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift4

This line `var machine = [CChar](_unsafeUninitializedCapacity: size, initializingWith: 0)` error throwing.

**Error Message:**

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '(inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<_>, inout Int) throws -> Void'

This is my Code:

```
struct MailTemplate {
    let destination = "test@gmail.com"
    let subject = "Test"
    let body:String

    init(){
        let appVersion: String! = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
        var platform: String {
            var size: Int = 0
            sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
            var machine = [CChar](_unsafeUninitializedCapacity: size, initializingWith: 0)
            sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
            return String.fromCString(machine)!
        }
        body = "Email Body"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got Answer,

```
initializingWith: {_,_ in}
```

Like that:

```
var machine = [CChar](_unsafeUninitializedCapacity: size, initializingWith: {_,_ in})
```

Answer (score 0):

`inout` parameters are those that are going to be modified by the function we are passing it to. Therefore, you need to pass it as `&size`.

Comment: When I pass the size I got this error :
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '(inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>, inout Int) throws -> Void' (aka '(inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int8>, inout Int) throws -> ()')

Comment: You need to pass a function. '(x, y) throws -> Void' is a function signature and you are passing int to it. But inout parameter needs be sent the way I mentioned above